Is there any way to write into database without select query using unique key in Entity Framework Core?
I want to update some properties in an entity, but I don't have the primary key property value. I do have the unique key value.
My expectation is to update directly without fetching by using that unique key property in Entity Framework Core using C#

Probably this, but the question is pretty vague.
